# Changing button value not working using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, button

I want to change the text of the span to *processing...* when user clicks

this is what I have tried already

```
$("#ibSave").text('Please wait...');
//$("#ibSave").prop('disabled', true);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../Messgaes.asmx/InsertMembers",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,

    timeout: 900000,
    data: JSON.stringify(Postdata),
    success: function (result) {
        $('#csvimporthint').html("<div class='success'>" + result.d + " members successfully uploaded.</div>")
        $("#ibSave").text('Upload');
        //$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ibSave').prop('disabled', false);
        console.log(new Date() - dates);
    },
    error: function (result) {
        console.log(result.responseText);
    }

});
```

This is my html

```
<span id="ibSave" class="btn btn-primary mr5">Upload</span>
```

I have also tried using [Jquery AJAX: How to Change button value on "success"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759749/jquery-ajax-how-to-change-button-value-on-success) solutions
**button("refresh")**
but some how its not working
*I was using button previously it wasn't working also*

```
$("#ibSave").val('Please wait...'); 
//when it was a button ^
$("#ibSave").val('Please wait...').button("refresh");
//this both wasn't working
```

Note: If I open the console in browser then value of button gets changed!!

I don't know what's I'm doing wrong same code with console window/ inspect window opened working fine.

Can you please guide me how to achieve this?

#### Updated :

Here's my full code

```
 $("#ibSave").click(function () {

     if ($('.green').length > 0) {
         var json = [];
         $('.green').each(function () {
             var firstname = '';
             var lastName = '';
             var email = '';
             var balance = '';
             var password = '';
             var obj = {},
             $td = $(this).find('td'),

                 firstname = $td.eq(0).text(),
                 lastName = $td.eq(1).text(),
                 email = $td.eq(2).text(),
                 balance = $td.eq(3).text();
             password = $td.eq(4).text();

             obj.FirstName = firstname;
             obj.LastName = lastName;
             obj.Email = email;
             obj.Balance = balance;
             obj.Password = password;
             json.push(obj);
         });
         //console.log(json);
         var Postdata = {
             members: json
         };
         var dates = new Date();


         $("#ibSave").html('Please wait...');
         //$("#ibSave").prop('disabled', true);
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "../Messgaes.asmx/InsertMembers",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",
             async: false,

             timeout: 900000,
             data: JSON.stringify(Postdata),
             success: function (result) {
                 $('#csvimporthint').html("<div class='success'>" + result.d + " members successfully uploaded.</div>")
                 $("#ibSave").html('Upload');
                 //$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ibSave').prop('disabled', false);
                 console.log(new Date() - dates);
             },
             error: function (result) {
                 console.log(result.responseText);
             }

         });
         return false;

     } else {
         alert("Sorry! you don't have enough valid rows to upload");
         return false;
     }
 });
```

Comment: its a <button> or <input>? can you please also share some html code of your problem

Comment: use .html() then instead of text()

Comment: @RohitBatra tried but not working

Comment: when i try with simple button click it works http://jsfiddle.net/aforpxsL/ . How'r you triggering the ajax?

Comment: @RohitBatra on button click

Comment: Can you update your whole code here? will give a idea if anything is wrong or any issue.

Comment: Some error on console? The code execute normally entering in success?

Comment: @RaúlMonge very thanks for the response I have resolved my problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to disturb but I will have to answer my own question for the future reference

I just had disabled

```
async: false,
```

I have changed it to

```
async: true,
```

And now its changing the values perfectly!

```
var interval;

                $this = $(this);
                //$("#ibSave").prop('disabled', true);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../Messgaes.asmx/InsertMembers",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: true,

                    beforeSend: function () {

                        $this.val('Uploading');

                        interval = window.setInterval(function () {
                            var text = $this.val();
                            if ($this.val().length < 13) {
                                $this.val($this.val() + '.');
                            } else {
                                $this.val('Uploading');
                            }
                        }, 200);
                    },
                    timeout: 900000,
                    data: JSON.stringify(Postdata),
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#csvimporthint').html("<div class='success'>"+result.d+" members successfully uploaded.</div>")
                        $this.val("Upload");
                        $this.prop('disabled', false);
                        //$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ibSave').prop('disabled', false);
                        $this.val('Calculating.....');
                        $this.val('Done!');
                        $this.val('Upload');
                        window.clearInterval(interval);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        console.log(result.responseText);
                    }

                });
```

here's ^ my full code

Special thanks to [@mr.Green](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1577396/mr-green)

Comment: By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to false. Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @RaúlMonge exactly this is where I was going wrong but didn't aware that browser will block my actions during the `sync` actions